# Rails - duplicate routes - upgrade from 3.2 to 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, upgrade

I've just upgraded my rails app from rails 3.2.21 to 4.2.0,

After fixed some error I have somes duplicates routes problems.

```
 `add_route': Invalid route name, already in use: 'contact'

You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming....
```

but ... yes, I have some route pointing on the same controller action, but this is the way I want it. How can I tell rails 4 to no take care of this, or theres is a way to not touch my routes?

thanls !

Comment: Can you post your route file?

Answer (score 1):

*The router in rails 4.0 detects whether a route name has been used before whereas previously it would've just overwritten them.* This is even listed on [`github`](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/10418).

**Fix:**

***Just make sure you are not using same helper method name for two routes in as: option***